# When I add <mvc:annotation-driven />, I get a "Error creating bean", "java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException"

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a simple application but when I try to add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to my servlet, I get this error :

```
[09/07/12 12:09:45:703 EDT] 00000053 DispatcherSer E org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean Context initialization failed
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

[09/07/12 12:09:45:718 EDT] 00000053 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0100E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet cm-dispatcher in application CM_ContractMaintenance: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
```

My Dispatcher servlet :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="ca.gc.ic.cipo.cm.web" />    

    <!-- Saves a locale change using a cookie -->
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" />

    <!-- Application Message Bundle -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean> 

    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

My Web.XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Contract Maintenance Web Application</display-name>

    <!-- Reads request input using UTF-8 encoding -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Handles all requests into the application -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cm-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/cm-dispatcher-servlet.xml
            </param-value>          
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cm-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security --> 
<!--    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
                  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
                </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>   
 -->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception
        </exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <!-- Datasource definition section -->
    <resource-ref>
        <description>The datasource reference for the Contract Maintenance
            Application. There will be a corresponding reference bound in
            'ibm-web-bnd.xml'.</description>
        <res-ref-name>CMDatasource</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

My pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>cipo-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>ca.gc.ic.cipo</groupId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>ca.gc.ic.cipo.cm</groupId>
  <artifactId>cm-webapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <name>cm-webapp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.security.version>

  </properties>

   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.gc.ic.cipo.cm</groupId>
        <artifactId>cm-product-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>          
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>      
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>      
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>      
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>      
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Reinject dependencies due to Spring Security -->
    <!--  Spring Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework --> 
    <dependency>         
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>         
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>         
        <version>${spring.version}</version>     
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Core Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Application Context --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring JDBC  --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Spring Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Core Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>cm-webapp</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

HELP!!

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are getting this error on Websphere - I am guessing that this is because the JSR 303 validator implementation provided by Websphere may be conflicting with the hibernate one which you have in your dependency. Can you try two things -

one is to remove hibernate-validator jar in your runtime deployment, this may force the validator to use the one provided by IBM,

the second if the first does not work, will be to force the use of hibernate validator. You can do it this way:

```
<bean name="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">

            <property name="validator">
                <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
                    <property name="providerClass" value="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator"></property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ca.gc.ic.cipo.cm.web" />
```

is where your controllers are, try to place the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` command just before it.

That's what I do on spring 3.0.5. I assume it's the same for 3.1.

Note as well that I also usually put my controllers via the `<context:component-scan` last after all the localresolver,viewresolvers, etc...
Too much magic in spring sometimes mess up the initialisation of the whole application.